# mysqli empty query issues

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

```
<?php 
include('dbConnection.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <?php
        //get the values from the form, using the POST method.
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $profession = $_POST['profession'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $date_of_birth = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
        $email = $_POST['first_name'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
       
       $query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$username' ";
       $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) ;
       
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
           echo $message ="WARNING: Book already exist!<br/>";
          
            
        }
        
        else {
    
        $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO user  (first_name,last_name,profession,gender,date_of_birth,email,username,password)" .
                    "VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$profession', '$gender', '$date_of_birth', '$email', '$username', '$password')";
        
        $queryInsert = mysqli_query($link,$resultInsert); 
        
        $resultInsert = mysqli_query($link,$queryInsert);
        {
            echo "<center><h2>It has been succesfully added!</h2><br>
                  Click <a href='manageBooks.php'>here</a> to manage  book(s)<br></center>";
            
        }}
        
        
        
    ?>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, i encountered 3 main issues when i ran this set of codes.

> Notice: Undefined variable: resultInsert in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\doRegister.php on line 38
>
> Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\doRegister.php on line 38
>
> Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\doRegister.php on line 40

Anyone is able to help guide me along on what i need to change accordingly?

Comment: You need to understand at least what's going on in your code.

Comment: hmm its mainly the empty query which i really dont understand

Comment: Edit: You're using `$resultInsert` at an *incorrect* place. Your query should be `$status = mysqli_query($link,$queryInsert); `. And you're executing the query two times.

Comment: And do you understand why do you run `mysqli_query` twice?

Comment: Bad Code. Bad Question.

Comment: To close things up, the reason I put `$status = ...` is because on successful insert it returns `true`, otherwise `false`, so you can check the status of your `INSERT` operation using `if($status){ // success }else{ // failure }`. And your braces are also incorrect. Fix them.

Comment: @A-2-A: absolutely right

Comment: @marcus please check the answers and mark and up-vote the answer for others help.

Comment: peoples are not interested in telling problem solved or not? wastage of effort. Deleting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the $resultIndex before it's defined.
Remove this line 38.

Answer (score 0):

You are using mysqli_query twice:

```
$queryInsert = mysqli_query($link,$resultInsert);
```

$resultInsert is not defined anywhere for this reason you are getting undefined variable error.

**Solution:**

If you want to run your query twice than you need to change the variable name here:

```
// first query

$queryInsert_Change = mysqli_query($link, $queryInsert );
```

**Side note**:

You code is open for **SQL injection**, you need to prevent your code with SQL Injection.

**Basic tips:**

Always remember if you get any notice like `Undefined variable` that means a variable is undefined in you code which needs to be defined either empty or with some value.